# what is the return type of Query method if there is no much in Room Database?

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-architecture-components

i know that @insert and @Update i can have them return an int , which will be the number of rows affected by the update or delete operation.

but what about @Query method ?

if we have this @Query method

`@Query("SELECT * FROM todos WHERE id= :id")
 LiveData<DailyTodo> findTodoById(long id);`

is there any specific return type for @Query method when there is no much in the database?

Comment: You can actually try this yourself. Call `findTodoById` with an ID that is not in your database

Comment: you are right ZUNJAE , it's return null. and the new problem is when i  do that my app is if there i no much in the database